# Auto-backup pendrive

Tags: windows, backup, usb-flash-drive

Do you guys know any tool for automatically copying the contents of a pendrive, once it's plugged in? And, if possible, run into the background?

Comment: You don't mention your OS - possibly `rsync` for *nix, "Briefcases" for Win32?

Comment: I'm under windows.

Answer (score 0):

May not be automatic but the free [Microsoft USB Flash Drive Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=94991901-bfc4-485e-bcae-c9df0accdaae) appears to store entire contents as images.  You can backup drives as images and archive them and then restore the images later.